# Cant understand ram formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Im trying to get how ram`s damage of a wall is calculated in travian. I saw this formula:

https://wbb.forum.travian.com/index.php?thread/75248-combat-system-formulas/

under ram, it states:

```
DDR = DC · { L·(L+1)/8 + 5 + (24.875 + 0.625·L2)·L2/2 } 
L2 = round{ (L – 1) / 2 }


L — starting level of wall.
DDR — Demolition Damage of Rams, equals percent of worked rams (9).
DC — Durability coefficient, depends on tribe, stonemason, rams' upgrades and durability artifact.
```

> There's a chart with 3 series below. Each series uses a corresponding
>   start wall level (see legend) and depicts the dependency between
>   amount of working rams and the intermediate wall level. We will use a
>   Roman city wall with no stonemason and artifacts.

[image]
How can i based on this formula, find out what damage X ram`s would do?

i dont quite understand how to read that formula.

im intrested to find out how many of my X ram`s would die, and the new wall level.

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with `contest-math` or `probability`, tagging as `algebra-precalculus`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the damage process is computed in two stages.

1. In the first stage, the ram replaces the wall's current level with a lower computed "virtual level", as if it were dealing actual damage. To compute the virtual level, use the formula (10). Formula (10) relates the number of attacking rams required to completely destroy the wall ("DDR") to the level and defensive factors of the wall. (It should also take into account the upgrade level, as catapults do in equation (8), but I don't see that factor here.)
2. As with equation (8) for catapults, equation (10) tells you how many attacking rams it takes to completely destroy the wall. I infer that "completely destroy the wall" means reduce its level to 0, and that if you have a fraction of that many rams, you reduce the wall's level by the same fraction of its total amount.
3. The chart, in any case, depicts the relationship between the wall's starting level and virtual level.  It is a plot showing how number of actual attacking rams (vertical axis) and the current level of the wall (curves show current level 10,15,20) relate to the wall's computed virtual level (horizontal axis). This may be just a plot of equation (10), but I have not plotted it to find out.
4. Once you've computed how low the wall's virtual level is, you conduct combat as usual. You use the virtual level instead of the wall's actual level when computing stats such as defensive bonus for troops.

The post leaves several things unclear, but my best guess is as follows:

- The ram casualties are determined using the usual casualty formula; just remember that the walls will use their virtual level when determining the defense bonus.
- The wall's level is reduced according to formula (10).  I suspect the level reduction is computed in the second stage (or else why call the level loss "virtual level loss".)  The level reduction is given by formula (10).